# "Nbextensions" tab not showing in jupyterhub

Tags: docker, jupyter, jupyterhub, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

can anyone explain how to fix or troubleshoot this issue ?
How i understand i already install packages and enable all modules.
There are no any issue(at least i can't see any) with requirements or versions.
But after login in jupyterhub, the "Nbextensions" tab is not showing.

Output of commands `jupyter --version` , `jupyter server extension list` and `jupyter nbextension list` is printed below.

```
# jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.8.0
ipykernel        : 6.20.2
ipywidgets       : not installed
jupyter_client   : 7.4.9
jupyter_core     : 5.1.3
jupyter_server   : 2.1.0
jupyterlab       : 3.5.3
nbclient         : 0.7.2
nbconvert        : 7.2.9
nbformat         : 5.7.3
notebook         : 6.5.2
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.6.0

# jupyter server extension list

Config dir: /root/.jupyter

Config dir: /usr/etc/jupyter

Config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter
jupyter_server_terminals enabled
\- Validating jupyter_server_terminals...
jupyter_server_terminals 0.4.4 OK
jupyterlab enabled
\- Validating jupyterlab...
jupyterlab 3.5.3 OK
nbclassic enabled
\- Validating nbclassic...
nbclassic 0.5.1 OK
notebook_shim enabled
\- Validating notebook_shim...
notebook_shim  OK

# jupyter nbextension list

Known nbextensions:
config dir: /root/.jupyter/nbconfig
notebook section
nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
varInspector/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
spellchecker/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
codefolding/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
tree section
nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
config dir: /usr/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
notebook section
nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
tree section
nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
notebook section
nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK
tree section
nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled
\- Validating: OK\
```

This commands i use for installation:

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 
pip install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
jupyter nbextension install --sys-prefix --py jupyter_nbextensions_configurator --overwrite
jupyter nbextension enable --sys-prefix --py jupyter_nbextensions_configurator 
jupyter serverextension enable --sys-prefix --py jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
```

Based on github thread:

https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/issues/127#issuecomment-1301506342